# A rare behavior of instanceof

Tags: java, class, inheritance, instanceof

I am trying to understand code of this tutorial:
[Java serial](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Two_way_communcation_with_the_serial_port)
specially in:

```
"if ( commPort instanceof SerialPort )"
```

that return true

```
"commPort" is CommPort class object
```

and
"SerialPort" is a class that inherits of CommPort class

how is possible that commPort could be instance of SerialPort class.

the correct would be, for example:

SerialPort serialPort;

```
"if ( serialPort instanceof CommPort )"
```

or i am wrong?
Thanks...

Comment: I don't know what exactly code does, but it's ok. It is checking if opened port which is a CommPort is from the type SerialPort or not. What's wrong with this?

Comment: I am understand that a parent object class is not instance of a child class but, yes child object class is instance of parent class.

Comment: Dude let me explain. You have a Class named Animal.
Human extends Animal.
Now you have an Animal named Jhon and you want to check if John is a Human or a Marmot?
then you say assertTrue(John instanceof Human)

Comment: In here you open a port which you sure is from type CommPort, but you want to check if it is also SerialPort? Or maybe ParallelPort (whatever) and use instanceof to realize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how is possible that commPort could be instance of SerialPort class.

You said

> "SerialPort" is a class that inherits of CommPort class

So you could do

```
CommPort commPort = new SerialPort();
if (commPort instanceof SerialPort) // true.
```

but if you write something like

```
CommPort commPort = new ParallelPort();
if (commPort instanceof SerialPort) // false
```